# AngularJS2 "Expression has changed after it was checked" exception when changing CSS class on click

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I am writing functionality to change the CSS class of a table on button click. The three buttons are grid view, thumbnail and list view. For some reason when I click any one of the options, I get a console error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'
    at ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedException.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4412:27)
    at new ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedException (http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8538:20)
    at checkBinding (http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8681:23)
    at DebugAppView._View_ShoppingTableComponent0.detectChangesInternal (ShoppingTableComponent.template.js:1125:7)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12143:18)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12247:48)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12169:23)
    at DebugAppView._View_ShoppingTableComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (ShoppingTableComponent.template.js:31:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12143:18)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12247:48)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

The buttons are  simple `<a>` tags that change the appearance depending on enum values 0,1 and 2 (where 0 is table, 1 is thumbnail, 2 is List) and looks like the following:

```
<a (click)="changeAppearance(0)" *ngIf="viewMode == 0" class="table-view view-item active"><i class="fa fa-table"></i></a>
<a (click)="changeAppearance(0)" *ngIf="viewMode != 0" class="table-view view-item"><i class="fa fa-table"></i></a>
<a (click)="changeAppearance(1)" *ngIf="viewMode == 1" class="list-view view-item active"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a>
<a (click)="changeAppearance(1)" *ngIf="viewMode != 1" class="list-view view-item"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a>
<a (click)="changeAppearance(2)" *ngIf="viewMode == 2" class="grid-view view-item active"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
<a (click)="changeAppearance(2)" *ngIf="viewMode != 2" class="grid-view view-item"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
```

Then in my component the changeAppearance method looks like the following:

```
changeAppearance(x: number) {
    this.viewMode = x;
        }
```

The function just changes the value of viewMode which defined to be 0(table view) onInit. I have tried changing the onInit value to 1 and 2 to confirm that it is not an error revolving around the CSS.

I believe it could be an AngularJS2 timeline or a change detection issue, but I'm not sure specifically what it could be.

Any help tackling this problem would be great.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this exception for this case. You can inject `private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` after `this.viewMode = x;` to get rid of the exception.

Comment: On a side node, you are duplicating thing. You should make use of `[class.active]="viewMode === 0"` to trim your markup.

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer this fixed the problem. However would you mind explaining the solution? Just so I know for future reference :)

Comment: Angular2 runs change detection and updates the view. In devMode (default) it runs change detection again immediately afterwards and if it again detects a change it throws above exception to indicate that your code hurts Angulars performance and is probably a bug. If you invoke detection explicitly after your change, then there is no change between the original change detection run and the addition change detection run anymore and you don't get the exception. If you enable prodMode, this additional change detection run doesn't happen - but you shouldn't enable it just to get rid of the exceptio